# How to extract particular field from rows from a file, based on matching subsequent rows

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

I am trying to replicate a workplace problem. I have a xml file like below

```
[~]$ less -N sample.xml
  1     <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" NAME ="TABLE1" FOO="ABCD"..... >
  2         <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" NAME ="COL_XYZ" />
  3         <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" NAME ="COL_ABCD" />
  4         ...
  5                 ...
  6     </SOURCE>
  7     <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" NAME ="TABLE2" ....... >
  8             <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" NAME ="COL_ABCD" />
  9         <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" NAME ="COL_XYZABC" />    
 10         ...
 11                 ...
 12     </SOURCE>
 13         <SOURCE BUSINESSNAME ="" NAME ="TABLE3" .... >
 14         <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" NAME ="COL_PQR" />
 15         <SOURCEFIELD BUSINESSNAME ="" NAME ="COL_ABCD" />
 16         ...
 17                 ...
 18     </SOURCE>
```

Now I want the value of `NAME` field where any of the `SOURCEFIELD NAME` is like `XYZ`.

For example, in the given example I need `TABLE1` as line 2 contains `COL_XYZ`. And also `TABLE2` as in line `9` we have `COL_XYZABC`

I was thinking some way, to get row `1,2,7,9,13` as output and then `grep -B1 XYZ|grep -w SOURCE` field to get only row `1,7` in output.

```
Expected Output:
TABLE1
TABLE2
```

**What I tried so far**

- Doing a grep on `SOURCE` is not working as every row has at least one of them.
- Doing a `egrep -w "SOURCE|XYZ"` is not working as I need `XYZABC` will not satisfy its condition.

Could someone please suggest something which I can try to get desired result. I am using `Linux 2.6.18-371.el5`

Comment: @mikeserv In the example above, `TABLE3` dont have a matching `XYZ` name (in line `14` and `15`). So I don't need `TABLE3` in output.

 The [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249258/139072) by [RobertL](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/139893/robertl) worked like a charm. I also came up with another [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249273/139072) which is slower than that but works. Thanks for giving it a thought anyways. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `hold space` feature of `sed`.

Run `sed` with the `-n` option to suppress the automatic printing of input lines.

When the line containing `<SOURCE` is seen, save the *value* of the `NAME` attribute in `sed`'s `hold space`.

When the `<SOURCEFIELD` line containing `XYZ` is seen, print the contents of the `hold space`.

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -n '
    /<SOURCE / {              # execute block {} on lines matching "<SOURCE "
        s/.* NAME *="//       # remove everything upto NAME attribute value
        s/".*//               # remove everything after attribute value
        h                     # copy pattern space to the hold space
    }
    /<SOURCEFIELD.*XYZ/ {     # SOURCEFIELD contains XYZ, execute {} block
        g                     # copy hold space to pattern space
        p                     # print
    }
' "$@"
```

Comment: I was also able to achieve this by this command but it is slower  `egrep -w ""\<SOURCE"|"SOURCEFIELD.*XYZ.*"" sample.xml|grep -B1 XYZ|grep -w SOURCE|awk -F" NAME =" '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'|sed 's/"//g'`

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed -netP -eH            -e'# Hold every line and test for s///uccess' \
    -e'\|<[^F]*[ >]|!d'  -e'# if < then F before [ >]: delete'         \
-ex -e'\|_XYZ[^_]*>|!d'  -e'# first exchange buffers; if !XYZ: delete' \
    -e's|[^"]*|\n&\n|4'  -e'# wrap 4th no quotes series in newlines'   \
    -e'D;:P' -eP         -e'# Delete up to first newline, :Print if true'
```

---

```
TABLE1
TABLE2
```

...and when I add an *`XYZ`* to the last field in the third list, *`TABLE3`* prints, too...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [RobertL](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/139893/robertl) for this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249258/139072).

I also came up with a combination of `grep/awk/sed` to achieve the same but it is slower obviously. Just wanted to put it out there.

```
egrep -w ""\<SOURCE"|"SOURCEFIELD.*XYZ.*"" sample.xml|grep -B1 XYZ|grep -w SOURCE|\                                                              
> awk -F" NAME =" '{print $2}'|awk '{print $1}'|sed 's/"//g'
```